# camelCase to snake_case using the shell?

Tags: regex, shell, text-processing, camelcasing, snakecasing

What's a simple way to convert (a stream of space-separated) words in camelCase to snake_case, using the command shell (e.g. bash)?

<sub>This is a simpler case relative to an earlier question which I've deleted.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed you can easily convert to lowercase and prefix with underscore:

```
$ echo camelCase andAnother | sed 's/[A-Z]/_\l&/g'
camel_case and_another
```

Comment: That's what I get for simplifying my question too much :-( Fair enough. Initially I also wanted to handle thisKINDOfIdentifiers.

Comment: You can make the `\l`sinto ae`\L` to lowercase all of them.  The pattern would have to be more complicated, though; simply adding a `+` after the `[A-Z]` would take one too many characters.  You’d need lookaheads to really handle it, probably, and I don’t knoweif POSIX EREs supprt those.

Comment: After playing around with it, I think you need a more complicated `sed` command: `sed -r -e 's/^([A-Z]+)([A-Z])/\L\1\E\2/' -e 's/^[A-Z]/\l&/' -e 's/[A-Z]+$/_\L&/' -e 's/([A-Z]+)([A-Z])/_\L\1\E\2/g' -e 's/[A-Z]/_\l&/g'` will do it, for *line*-separated words instead of *space-separated* ones.  That also handles `PascalCase` instead of `camelCase`.

Comment: (If you want I can make a full answer explaining that, but not now)